# Kong - Structured Json Logs

Tags: fluentd, kong

I can not find an example to output Kongs logs as JSONto system out. I am currently using Fluentd to ingest logs from my Kubernetes cluster but I have no idea how to send those logs to Fluentd as structured JSON.

Comment: Kong logs are just nginx. You can probably use the [Fluentd nginx parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is struggling with this, I made the following updates to the kong helm chart values.

```
env:
  admin_access_log: '/dev/stdout structured_logs'
  proxy_access_log: '/dev/stdout structured_logs'
  nginx_http_log_format: |
     structured_logs escape=json '{"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "remote_user": "$remote_user", "host": "$host"...}
```

Comment: the last line looks like it's missing some values or a closing single-quote...

Comment: Found this example that might be helpful: `'{"source": "nginx", "time": $msec, "resp_body_size": $body_bytes_sent, "host": "$http_host", "address": "$remote_addr", "request_length": $request_length, "method": "$request_method", "uri": "$request_uri", "status": $status,  "user_agent": "$http_user_agent", "resp_time": $request_time, "upstream_addr": "$upstream_addr"}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the file-log plugin? https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/file-log/

It lets you log to /dev/stdout and use lua to remove/add fields if necessary.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get it to work with file log plugin. So I ended up using the NGINX directives.

Comment: Same here, it's hard to log to stdout in containers, seems like..

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work, I had some conflicting config in my helm chart template that I had to straighten out, but I was able to get file log to log to `/dev/stdout` just fine, using the example in the file log docs with `/dev/stdout` as the path.